# Printing all Blanks (literally no tokens are printed)

Tags: c++, strtok

Basically my code doesn't print the tokens. It just prints blanks. What am I doing wrong?
I've consulted many other guides on this issue and I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  stack<double> s;
  string str = "";
  getline(cin, str);
  char *cstr = new char [str.length()+1];
  strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());
  char* strp = strtok(cstr, " ");
  while (strp != 0){
        double n = strtod(cstr, &strp);
        s.push(n);
        cout << strp << endl;
        strp = strtok(0," "); 
        }
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What is the input you're providing?

Comment: `double n = strtod(cstr, &strp);` is wrong. should be `double n = strtod(strp, &other_pointer);`

Comment: @Retired Ninja 2 3 + // output is 3 blank spaces

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm not sure what you mean, those parameters don't correspond to the ones here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/
and I hardly think that is the problem with the tokens anyway.

Comment: This would be much easier (and more idiomatic C++) with `istringstream` instead of `strtok`+`strtod`.

Comment: @interjay Yeah I think I'm gonna botch the whole strtok implementation and go with that instead. In what case would strtok be useful? I'm still curious how to do it properly with this route.

Comment: `strtod`, if successful, makes the provided pointer point to the position right after the token, so yeah, it would print nothing.  It's worth noting that without the `strtod` line and the one below it all the tokens provided are printed properly.

Comment: @AlexElkman read document again. and try my commnet.

Comment: @ BLUEPIXY Retired Ninja Oh yeah you're right. I'm a noob. Still don't understand why this works though... Ok I guess it's because it wasn't a NULL pointer so it did what Ninja said. Very odd way to set up this function in my opinion.

Comment: read document again.

Comment: So basically it wasn't NULL, and then it just pointed to the first character after which was a ' ' and then it just printed that instead. I just don't understand why it looks for a NULL pointer in the first place, like what is the point of that?

Comment: The reason the end pointer is passed is so that you can detect the difference between successfully parsing a 0 and not parsing anything which would also return 0.  That's the reason it is more useful that `atof`.  That said, in C++ there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
int main()
{
   stack<double> s;
   string str = "";
   getline(cin, str);
   char *cstr = new char [str.length()+1];
   strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());
   char* strp = strtok(cstr, " ");
   while (strp != NULL)
   {
      double n = strtod(strp, NULL);
      s.push(n);
      cout << n << endl;
      strp = strtok(NULL, " "); 
   }

   return 0;
}
```

But hell, this really is a painfull mix of C and C++. You should get rid of those strcpy, strtok and strod functions. Use istringstream instead.

Comment: Yeah my professor used strtok in some of his sample programs (for C++ course) so I wanted to try doing it this way since I don't have much knowledge of C at all. It would probably be much more straightforward with istringstream route.